# Setting up an Alias in tcsh for a function defined in a bash script

Tags: bash, function, shell, alias, tcsh

I have a cshrc file with aliases, in that file I want to set up an alias that point to a function defined in a bash file.

bash function file AliasFunc:

```
function aaa() 
{

 echo stackoverflow

}
```

Example .cshrc file:

```
bash -c 'source AliasFunc'

alias bashfunc aaa

bashfunc #calling bashfunc
```

sourcing the .cshrc file results in the following error:

```
bashfunc: Command not found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `bash -c 'source AliasFunc'` in your cshrc file does is start a new bash shell, load the `AliasFunc` file, and exit. It will not affect the parent csh shell at all.

It just so happens that bash and csh both have a `source` keyword, but that doesn't mean it's somehow "compatible". What you're trying to do now is equivalent of trying to import a Python module in Perl by starting a new Python process from within a Perl program.

What you can do is something along the lines of:

```
$ alias bashfunc 'bash -c "source AliasFunc && aaa"'
$ bashfunc
stackoverflow
```

Every time the `bashfunc` alias is invoked it will start a new bash shell which will source the `AliasFunc` file *and* will immediately run the bash `aaa` function.